Disabling the specified IP
I need to reject the connection of the specified IP address to a server (shadowsocks) running on a specific port. I am doing this in order to limit the number of simultaneous connections to the server. I wrote a program that detects an "extra" device (IP address). I tried disabling/rejecting it using the socket library in Python, but socket requires connection to the specified port, but it is already occupied by the server. I've also tried tools like "cutter", "tcpkill", but they don't work for me.
def drop_connections(ip, port):
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    s.close()
    print(f"Connection to {ip}:{port} closed successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error while closing connection: {e}")


Wouldn't a firewall rule to reject connections from that ip be easier?

I've tried adding rules using iptables, but it doesn't work. As I understand it, iptables works precisely with the "connections" that the device itself makes. And it is the "device/client" that I need to disable. This is the command I tried to enter: sudo iptables -A INPUT -p 6 --syn --dport 10000 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 -j DROP. That is, I wanted only one person/one device to be able to connect to port 10000.
